# How to dump YUV from OMXCodec decoding output

Tags: android, dump, yuv, stagefright

I'd like to dump `YUV` data from `OMXCodec` decoding output.
It's `MediaBuffer` type. It's impossible to access data() pointer.

If I try to access data, crash happens due to the check code below.

```
frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MediaBuffer.cpp:119 CHECK(mGraphicBuffer == NULL) failed.
```

Please let me know the solution to extract `YUV` data from this `MediaBuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

From the `MediaBuffer`, I feel that the following should be functional. I haven't tried the same yet and have worked with rg2's solution i.e. directly based on `gralloc` handle, but feel that the following should also be functional.

```
 sp<GraphicBuffer> mCurrGraphicBuffer;
 void *vaddr;

 err = source->read(&buffer, &options); // Where buffer is of MediaBuffer type

 mCurrGraphicBuffer = buffer->graphicBuffer();
 width  = mCurrGraphicBuffer->getWidth();
 height = mCurrGraphicBuffer->getWidth();
 format = mCurrGraphicBuffer->getFormat();

 mCurrGraphicBuffer->lock(GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_READ_OFTEN, &vaddr);
 //Dump the YUV file based on the vaddr, width, height, format
 mCurrGraphicBuffer->unlock();
```

**EDIT:**

In order for the aforementioned solution to work, the actual `GraphicBuffer` should be created or allocated with appropriate usage flags i.e. the buffer should be created with a hint that CPU would be accessing the same. Else, `-EINVAL` would be returned as per the [documentation in `gralloc`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/hardware/libhardware/include/hardware/gralloc.h#175).

Comment: Thank you very much.
From your comment, I could extract YUV data from MediaBuffer.
But, this colorformat is "OMX_QCOM_COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8ka".
and I need to convert it to YUV420Planar.
Can I find the convert function?

Comment: @user2453912.. Please check my comment in this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797923/qomx-color-formatyuv420packedsemiplanar64x32tile2m8ka-converter . I presume you only asked the same

Comment: @user2453912.. Can you please accept the response if it answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you using?

1) Usually the easiest way to get output buffer dump is to do it in vendor OMX IL (in every vendor impl which I worked there were ready functions/macros to do it)

2) If not you should try to dump buffer in ACodec `onFillBufferDone` (you need to differentiate between audio/video) or `onOutputBufferDrained`, you must get `mGraphicBuffer` and get from it raw buffer - encapsulation is platform dependent eg for qc it would be

```
void const *buf = (void const*)((private_handle_t*)(info->mGraphicBuffer->handle))->base;
```

Assuming that info is (in ACodec::onOutputBufferDrained)

```
    BufferInfo *info =
    mCodec->findBufferByID(kPortIndexOutput, bufferID, &index);
```

In OMXCodec case you can make the same at the end of OMXCodec::read
Returned buf just save into the file, size to be written will be WxHxPixelRatio.

Answer (score 0):

On some platforms, the hardware decoder does not create user-space YUV by default. You may try

```
OMXCodec::Create(…,
    flags | OMXCodec::kClientNeedsFramebuffer);
```