# H264 HW accelerated decoding in Android using stagefright library

Tags: android-ndk, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration, stagefright

I`m trying to decode h264 video using HW with Stagefright library.

i have used an example in [here](https://vec.io/posts/use-android-hardware-decoder-with-omxcodec-in-ndk). Im getting decoded data in `MedaBuffer`. For rendering `MediaBuffer->data()` i tried `AwesomeLocalRenderer` in AwesomePlayer.cpp.

but picture in screen are distorted

Here is The   [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rg0x46cjikhn3bx/Screensho.png) of original and crashed picture.

And also tried this in example`

```cpp
sp<MetaData> metaData = mVideoBuffer->meta_data();
int64_t timeUs = 0;
metaData->findInt64(kKeyTime, &timeUs);
native_window_set_buffers_timestamp(mNativeWindow.get(), timeUs * 1000);
err = mNativeWindow->queueBuffer(mNativeWindow.get(), 
mVideoBuffer->graphicBuffer().get(), -1);`
```

But my native code crashes. I can`t get real picture its or corrupted or it black screen.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: FWIW, there are public APIs for this in Android 4.1+.  The bad image looks like a stride/alignment problem in a YUV buffer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. But i want to work with Android 4.0+. 
Thats why i`m using Android NDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `HW` accelerated decoder, then the allocation on the output port of your component would have been based on a `Native Window`. In other words, the output buffer is basically a `gralloc` handle which has been passed by the `Stagefright` framework. (Ref: [`OMXCodec::allocateOutputBuffersFromNativeWindow`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#1703)). Hence, the `MediaBuffer` being returned shouldn't be interpreted as a plain `YUV` buffer.

In case of [`AwesomeLocalRenderer`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp#100), the framework performs a software color conversion when [`mTarget->render`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/colorconversion/SoftwareRenderer.cpp#140) is invoked as shown here. If you trace the code flow, you will find that the `MediaBuffer` content is directly interpreted as `YUV` buffer.

For `HW` accelerated codecs, you should be employing [`AwesomeNativeWindowRenderer`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp#125). If you have any special conditions for employing `AwesomeLocalRenderer`, please do highlight the same. I can refine this response appropriately.

**P.S:** For debug purposes, you could also refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717728/how-to-dump-yuv-from-omxcodec-decoding-output) which captured the methods to dump the YUV data and analyze the same.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. First when i tried AwesomeNativeWindowRenderer,native code crashes. Here is how i used it. 
        mVideoRenderer = new AwesomeNativeWindowRenderer (mNativeWindow, 0);
        mVideoRenderer->render(mVideoBuffer); //In while Loop. 

This is backtrace.
#00  pc 00000000  <unknown>
#01  pc 00005678  mylib.so (AwesomeNativeWindowRenderer::render (android::MediaBuffer*)+260)

And when im using addr2line, the error in this line of this
status_t err = mNativeWindow->queueBuffer(mNativeWindow.get(), buffer->graphicBuffer().get(), 
-1);
The error in probably in -1.

Comment: @user3215358.. In your code, how did you create `mNativeWindow`? The -1 is present in `AOSP` code and hence, I will not doubt it. Can you share your code for a review? `mNativeWindow` should point to a `Surface` or `SurfaceTextureClient` which internally has a `SurfaceTexture` attached to the same. My doubt is `mNativeWindow` may not be populated properly.

Comment: @Ganesh.. Im getting mNativeWindow from SurfaceView. Here is the code how im getting it  [link](http://pastebin.com/ZefHRW2z).

Comment: @Ganesh.. Im using [This](https://github.com/roman10/android-ffmpeg-tutorial/blob/master/android-ffmpeg-tutorial02/jni/tutorial02.c) Tutorial And im changing reading and decoding part.

Comment: @user3215358.. I will require some time to review.. but can you quickly enable logs in `BufferQueue` and check?

Comment: @Ganesh.. How to enable logs? open comment //#define LOG_NDEBUG 0 and recompile it ?

Comment: @user3215358..Yes that's correct.. If you are enabling for `BufferQueue`, consider doing so for `SurfaceTextureClient` and `SurfaceTexture` also

Comment: @Ganesh.. i have added #defind LOG_NDEBUG 0 But nothing was changed. Was else i should do, to see the problem???

Comment: @user3215358.. Did you capture the logs in `logcat`? If so, can you share the same?

Comment: @Ganesh.. [Here](http://pastebin.com/FCYUxrRr) is the paste of logcat, But i dont see any logs about BufferQueue. 
And i have a question, Am i doing something wrong in my code???

Comment: @Ganesh.. in `queueBuffer`, second parameter is `NULL`. 
`buffer->graphicBuffer()` is `NULL`. What can be the problem?

Comment: @user3215358.. Sorry I couldn't read your code. Can you please reshare your code and logcat? I can have a quick look

Comment: @Ganesh.. Now i'm using [this](https://vec.io/posts/use-android-hardware-decoder-with-omxcodec-in-ndk) example. For rendering i can use or local rendering or native window rendering. what do you advise? 
[This](http://pastebin.com/iD81dSFY) is my main part of code. 
[This](http://pastebin.com/WAS2DwDd) is renderers.